# converting dates to a desired format

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm working with an array containing data received from an api. Each object in the array has a createdOn field that is a date. I'm having a problem converting this dates to the format YYYYDDMMHHmmss since not all the dates are in the same format.

sample dates are as follow :

date1 = 20190425125221, 
date2 = Wed, 30 Jan 2019 08:57:17 GMT

I created another array that will contain all the converted dates. I tried using the angular date pipe to transform the dates to a unified format and then used momentjs to convert the dates to my desired format but i get "invalidDate".

like

```
constructor(private transformer: DatePipe) {}
   ....
const myNewArr = arr.map((val, i, arr) => {

const myDate = this.transformer.transform(val.createdOn, 'MMM/dd/yyyy');

const convertedDate=moment(myDate,'MMM/dd/yyyy').format('YYYYDDMMHHmmss');

return convertedDate;
});

...
```

i expect the the converted dates to resemble this date pattern 'YYYYDDMMHHmmss'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `if` loop to differentiate different date formats. For example, the line `const convertedDate=moment(myDate,'MMM/dd/yyyy').format('YYYYDDMMHHmmss');` can be rewritten as

```
let convertedDate;
if (isNaN(myDate)) {
 convertedDate = moment(myDate,'MMM/dd/yyyy').format('YYYYDDMMHHmmss');
} else {
convertedDate = myDate; // already in YYYYDDMMHHmmss format like date1
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. This helped solve my issue and i'm glad the convertedDate is as expected. Could you please guide on how to compare this dates with the date today so i can come up with a list of only those that were created today. I have tried    ` moment(convertedDate).isSame(moment()); ` but all of them return false where as there exists some that are true