# table request in db returns date like this: 2023-07-20T21:39:00.000Z I need to format this data to dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: typescript

In the database the format is correct, but in the ts request it is arriving this way, how can I correct it?

```js
cols: any[] = [
  {
    field: 'dataHoraInicio',
    header: 'Início',
    fieldback: 'dataHoraInicio'
  },
  {
    field: 'dataHoraFim',
    header: 'Final',
    fieldback: 'dataHoraFim'
  }
]
```

The only thing I found was formatting for fixed codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting dates to a desired format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851656/converting-dates-to-a-desired-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a TypeScript (TS) function that returns the formatted date as a string:

```
function formatDate(inputDate) {
  // Convert the input string to a Date object
  const date = new Date(inputDate);

  // Get the day with leading zeros
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the month with leading zeros
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the year
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  // Get the hours with leading zeros
  const hours = String(date.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the minutes with leading zeros
  const minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Format the date as dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
  const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`;

  return formattedDate;
}
```

Now use the above function to get the formatted date like this:

```
const inputDate = '2023-09-18T12:52:45.000Z';
const formattedDate = formatDate(inputDate);
console.log(formattedDate); // Output: "18/09/2023 18:22"
```

```js
function formatDate(inputDate) {
  // Convert the input string to a Date object
  const date = new Date(inputDate);

  // Get the day with leading zeros
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the month with leading zeros (Note: Months are zero-based)
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the year
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  // Get the hours with leading zeros
  const hours = String(date.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Get the minutes with leading zeros
  const minutes = String(date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');

  // Format the date as dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
  const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`;

  return formattedDate;
}

const inputDate = '2023-09-18T12:52:45.000Z'; // Replace this with desired date
const formattedDate = formatDate(inputDate);
console.log(formattedDate);
```